# Based on ID values , how to find the columns which has values for the ID in a table?

Tags: sql-server

I have table where there is an identity column . For each ID , the other columns would have 0 or 1 as a value . I need to find how many columns have 1s and list those as comma separated string .

This is my table

```
ID  T1  T2  T3
1   1    0  0
2   0    1  1
3   1    1  1
```

Expected Output

```
ID   1      2       3-- COLUMNS 
1    t1     t2,t3   t1,t2,t3
```

under Column 1 , the value should be "t1" since t1 had the value '1'

under Column 2 , the value should be "t2,t3" since t2,t3 had the value '1'

under Column 3 , the value should be "t1,t2,t3" since t1,t2,t3 had the value '1'

Any help how to achieve this output ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is there an `ID` of `1` in your second tables when clearly that row isn't related to `ID` `1`. Seems like, however, you need a pivot and string aggregation; which there are 100's of examples of both on SO. Have a look at the existing answers out there, and if you get stuck post your attempts and we'll be happy to show you where you went wrong. We aren't, however, a free coding service, so we can't just "answer" the question for you when we can't see what you've already tried.

Comment: This smells a lot like a homework assignment, and an odd one at that.

Comment: Yeah this is either a really horrific homework assignment or an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I could not think of any  approach . I was searching for any clue but did not come across any . So I posted here . But fortunately , I was able to find a solution . I am posting the answer below . @Larnu : ID column in the second table is not the same one in the first table . it can even be ignored  if that confuses you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT ID, CASE WHEN T1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'T1' END AS T1, CASE WHEN T2 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'T2' END AS T2, CASE WHEN T3 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'T3' END AS T3 FROM Foo 
)
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(CONCAT(', ' + T1, ', ' + T2, ', ' + T3), 3, 100) AS Result FROM T
```

The first select converts the columns into their names or `NULL`, the second concatenates them into a comma (+ space) delimitered list.

Comment: This is the simpler solution I could find . With this result , I could do a pivot and get the expected Output . Thank you so much . I have learnt to write this in more simpler way .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple function to enable your task then export the file from the SQL Server as a .csv file and then apply the concatenate function on excel side.

=CONCATENATE(A1, ", ", B1)

On SQL side, 
CONCAT(string1, string2, ...., string_n)

Comment: Why not use CONCAT in sql server and avoid the manual steps of doing this in excel?

Comment: Thank you for the effort to help me in this . But I was looking for a query without using files . Anyway could resolve this in another way as posted below :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for your help .

I was able to get the required result from the below code . But the one which @Christoph posted is much more simpler than mine .

Anyway posting my approach as below .

```
select u.ID, u.Columns1, u.values1 into #temptable from ColumnsAsValues s

unpivot
(
  values1
  for Columns1 in (t1,t2,t3,t4)
) u;



SELECT DISTINCT MC2.ID, 
            (
                SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + MC1.Columns1  AS [text()] 
                FROM #temptable MC1
                WHERE MC1.ID = MC2.ID and values1=1
                ORDER BY MC1.ID
                FOR XML PATH (''),type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
            ) [ColumnsWith1]
            INTO #CommaSeparatedString
            FROM #temptable MC2



            select * from 
            ( select id , [ColumnsWith1] from 
            #CommaSeparatedString ) datatable pivot (max(ColumnsWith1) for id in ([1],[2],[3]))piv;
```